# Rails Simple Form - No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Each user can create a number of blogs and, when they log in, they are presented with a list of their blogs and a button next to each as below:

```
= simple_form_for activate_blog_path(blog.id), method: :put do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :active, value: true
  = f.button :submit
```

Even though the path exists in routes, I'm still getting this error message:

```
No route matches [PUT] "/"
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :users
resources :blogs do
  member do
    get :activate
    put :activate
  end
end
root 'pages#index'
```

rails routes:

```
       Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        users GET    /users(.:format)               users#index
              POST   /users(.:format)               users#create
     new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)           users#new
    edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)      users#edit
         user GET    /users/:id(.:format)           users#show
              PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
              PUT    /users/:id(.:format)           users#update
              DELETE /users/:id(.:format)           users#destroy
activate_blog GET    /blogs/:id/activate(.:format)  blogs#activate
              PUT    /blogs/:id/activate(.:format)  blogs#activate
        blogs GET    /blogs(.:format)               blogs#index
              POST   /blogs(.:format)               blogs#create
     new_blog GET    /blogs/new(.:format)           blogs#new
    edit_blog GET    /blogs/:id/edit(.:format)      blogs#edit
         blog GET    /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#show
              PATCH  /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#update
              PUT    /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#update
              DELETE /blogs/:id(.:format)           blogs#destroy
         root GET    /                              pages#index
```

blogs_controller.rb:

```
  def activate
    @blog.active = true
    @blog.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you post the complete error message?

Comment: That's all it says

Comment: Did it said something like missing required keys `:id`?

Comment: Nope. I'm passing in the required key already.

Comment: I guess simple form is not formatted. It may cause the error.  Try: `simple_form_for blog, url: activate_blog_path, method: :put`

Comment: The fact that you have one method for put and get? Try to comment the get in the routes.

Comment: Tried changing the format and removing get. Neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simple_form_for` expects an object (or record) to generate the form tag. To pass custom url and method to a form action you could use

```
= simple_form_for blog, url: activate_blog_path(blog.id), method: :put do |f|
  = hidden_field_tag :active, value: true
  = f.button :submit
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the action and controller as well as the method

```
= simple_form_for blog, url: url_for(action: :activate, controller: 'blogs'), method: :put do |f|
```

Comment: I get this error: No route matches {:action=>"activate", :controller=>"blogs"}

Comment: I'm curious that you got an error as it worked fine for me.